# Regular expression to find number in parentheses, but only at beginning of string

Tags: regex

Disclaimer: I'm new to writing regular expressions, so the only problem may be my lack of experience.

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will find numbers inside of parentheses, and I want both the numbers and the parentheses to be included in the selection. However, I only want it to match if it's at the beginning of a string. So in the text below, I would want it to get (10), but not (2) or (Figure 50).

```
(10) Joystick Switch - Contains control switches (Figure 50)
Two (2) heavy lifting straps
```

So far, I have `(\(\d+\))` which gets (10) but also (2). I know ^ is supposed to match the beginning of a string (or line), but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've looked at a lot of similar questions, both here and on other sites, but have only found parts of solutions (finding things inside of parentheses, finding just numbers at the beginning for a string, etc.) and haven't quite been able to put them together to work.

I'm using this to create a filter in a CAT tool (for those of you in translation) which means that there's no other coding languages involved; essentially, I've been using [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) to test all of the other expressions I've written, and that's worked fine.

Comment: `^(\(\d+\))` should work just fine. We can't really say why it wouldn't work without you posting the expression you used and more importantly, *how* you applied the expression (which language? which specific method? etc).

Comment: Maybe you have to escape `^`?

Answer (score 8):

The regex should be

```
^\(\d+\)
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `\(` Matches `(`. Should be escaped as it has got special meaning in regex
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits
- `\)` Matches the `)`
- Capturing brackets like `(\(\d+\))` are not necessary as there are no other characters matched from the pattern. It is required only when you require to extract parts from a matched pattern

  For example if you like to match `(50)` but to extract digits, `50` from the pattern then you can use

  ```
  \((\d+)\)
  ```

  here the `\d+` part comes within the captured group 1, That is the captured group 1 will be `50` where as the entire string matched is `(50)`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aN0yN3/1)

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
^\(\d+\)
```

`^` anchor

Each of `(` and `)` are regex meta character, so they need to be escaped with `\`

So `\(`  and `\)` match literal parenthesis.

`(` and `)` captures.

`\d+` match 1 or more digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW9bQ7/1)